# How do I save a lambda for later callback?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

How do I fix the code below to store a lambda so I can invoke it at a later time?

The error I currently get is **field 'm_callback' has incomplete type**.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo()  { }
        ~Foo() { }

        template< typename FuncT > 
        void setCallback( FuncT&& callback )
        {
            m_callback = callback;
        }

    private:
        auto m_callback;   // this line is broken
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo foo;

    foo.setCallback( [] (int x){ return true; } );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m_callback = callback;` should be `m_callback = std::forward<FuncT>(callback);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `auto` keyword can't be used liked that.  I recommend using something like this:

```
#include <functional>
std::function<bool (int)> m_callback;
```

This is done from Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: hmm...  ...this answer works well, if I know, beforehand, the signature of the lambda.  What if I don't know the signature (for instance, I really want to pass in a void* that goes in and comes back later, but doesn't get invoked inside Foo)?

Comment: @kfmfe04 : C++ is statically typed -- you **need** to know your signature in advance. If you want to support multiple signatures, have a look at [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/).

Answer (score 7):

The `auto` keyword can only be used in conjunction with an **initalization expression**.

So... this works:

```
auto callback = [](int x){ return x == 0; };
```

... but this doesn't:

```
auto callback;
callback = [](int x){ return x == 0; };
```

I would recommend that you use something like [`function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982519.aspx) with a specific signature to represent a callback.

Comment: To be more precise, in the second case, `auto` is interpreted as being a *storage specifier*, like `register`. In the old days of `C`, `auto` was the default storage specifier and meant *automatic storage* (which for most compilers, is the ubiquitous stack). Of course, since it is the default... it was not really useful to precise it, so it was rarely used in practice.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: In C++11, `auto` as a storage-specifier is completely removed.

Comment: @GMan: oh! I thought it had only been deprecated :x

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Nope. It's unusual for them to make a straight jump like that for sure, but that just shows, as you say, how useless it really was.